# Javascript: Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, variables

**Is this possible?**

```
var [a+b] = something;
```

**a**: is defined by me. ex: "object"

**b**: is a variable. ex: "2"

Comment: What are you _trying_ to do? Add a to b?

Comment: Maybe he's trying to name a variable with the concatenation of a and b.

Comment: Can't see what are you trying to achieve, seems to me like you want an array variable and access items by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve. You can't create a variable simply by putting strings together in brackets, but you can use brackets to add a name/value pair to an object. For instance, if you wanted to add this value to object myNewObj, you can do something like this:

```
var myNewObj = {};
myNewObj[ a + b ] = something;
```

Comment: hmm so after this I could call it in this way? `myNewObj.ab`?

Comment: No you could access it this way: `myNewObj[a+b]`.

Comment: after adding it, you could access it using [] or ".", but you can't just concatenate the variable names when using ".", for instance, if you set a = "first" and b = "Second", you could access it any of these ways: myNewObj.firstSecond, myNewObj["first" + "Second"], myNewObject[ a + b ], myNewObj["first" + b], but NOT myNewObj.ab

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to set a value to something that represents the combination of `a` and `b`, why not do something like:

```
var obj = {};
obj[a] = {};
obj[a][b] = "something";
```

Not as short as `obj[a+b] = "something"` but it's more reliable, since

```
a = "object"
b = "2"
```

and,

```
a = "objec"
b = "t2"
```

are indistinguishable using `obj[a+b]`

Comment: Not sure what he's trying to achieve, but I feel this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about locals, but for globals you could use `window[a+b]` to access the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Shoot me down if I'm wrong here, but it looks like you're trying to dynamically define your variable names so that you might have

```
var myVar1 = something;
var myVar2 = something;
```

And so on.

AFAIK you can't do this in JavaScript or any declarative language.  Your better approach would likely be to use arrays in this instance.  What are your actual drivers for needing the approach you're asking about?

Comment: Lol no one will shoot you! :D however I dont think that you are right, with the window object it's easily possible, but I don't think that this would be the best way to define these variables there. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but think that you have a syntax error in the code snippet above. But, if your question is to assign something to a dynamic location in an array, then you can do it

Follow the sample code below

```
var a = 5; 
var array = [];

function someFunction(b){
  array[a+b] = 'hello'
}


someFunction(5);
alert(array[10]);
```

Answer (score 1):

as the rest of the guys here I don't really understand your purpose here but you could write this :

```
var a ='te';
var b = 'st';
eval ('(' + a + b + ' = 3)');
alert (test);
```